# PHP Imagick Caption with Interline Spacing

Tags: php, imagick

How can I apply Text Interline Spacing to a Caption?
Through **ImageMagick** command line is possible. But through the PHP **Imagick** library I can not.

According to the API only ImagickDraw has Interline Spacing: `ImagickDraw:: setTextInterlineSpacing`.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
$image = new Imagick("http://placehold.it/1280x720");

$text = new Imagick();

$text->setBackgroundColor('transparent');

$text->newPseudoImage(300, 200, 'caption:Test\nTest!');

$image->compositeImage($text, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
```

Any tips on how I can apply Interline to a caption?

Comment: I do not think that feature is implemented in Imagick as far as I know. One way is to do the caption: via PHP exec(). Or use multiple label: commands and composite them with -geometry as desired to replicate your desired interline spacing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was this feature. I think I'm going for the exec, because I do not want to deal with word count per line and all that routine.